# Is Content-Transfer-Encoding an HTML header?

Tags: c#, html, encoding, outlook, content-encoding

We are sending an automated email with mail's body in HTML format and we are receiving the email content twice in the body.Once with this header

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_00F5_01D2C509.C9598370"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 16.0
Thread-Index: AdLE260N6ZrXujJMTE6odOelzNRIhw==
Content-Language: en-us

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_00F5_01D2C509.C9598370
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

and then with this header

```
------=_NextPart_000_00F5_01D2C509.C9598370
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

also tried having the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header in html having one of  these values `"BASE64" / "QUOTED-PRINTABLE" / "8BIT" / "7BIT" / "BINARY" / "x-token"`.
 But still having the same headers of MIME in the received mail.
So firstly, Is Content-Transfer-Encoding an HTML header? If yes, will changing the value of this header to a correct value will fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Content-Transfer-Encoding an HTML header?

No, it is not related to HTML or to to be exact "just HTML". "`Content-Transfer-Encoding`" is *the header of the particular content* of the MIME (it may be HTML content as well) *which indicate encoding of this content* when added to MIME to transfer this content. I know it sounds a bit weird, content, content and content, but may be this resource would help you to understand better: [Content-Transfer-Encoding Header Field](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html). The `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is designed to specify an invertible mapping between the "native" representation of a type of data and a representation that can be readily exchanged using 7 bit mail transport protocols. But enough theory, lets do some real world example you have ...

You compose your message with Outlook in HTML format. When message will leave Exchange environment (sent out) it will be converted to MIME to travel through Internet. At this point your HTML will be encoded with appropriate, to the content of this HTML, type and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header will be added to this content, so the recipient of this message able to convert this content back to original HTML by decoding the content. I hope this clear now.

> We are sending an automated email with mail's body in HTML format and we are receiving the email content twice in the body

According to [rfc2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) for Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) Alternative Subtypes of the same body (your HTML content) were created at the time message was converted into MIME and appropreate header was added to indicate that "`Content-Type: multipart/alternative;`". Each of the body parts is an "alternative" version of the same information. This means you have "`text/plain`" content, which represent nothing else as strip off version of your HTML to bare text. This content is alternative to HTML and has it's own `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header based on the content. This content may be used by the recipients who do not have ability to render HTML.

Comment: How do you do this? I can see the Mailer is Outlook. Do you have add-in? Anyways Outlook work with objects only. All conversion from the objects into MIME happen on Exchange with [MIME Converter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232174%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), when message is sent out of Exchange environment.

Comment: I'm not adding meta tag to MIME .I'm adding the meta tag in head section of mail body which is in html format.

Comment: You are sending with Outlook, Exchange will override this value to optimize size of the message. You still didn't answer "how do you do this?" You didn't mention about that anything in your question and would like to get technical answer.

Comment: Sorry, @Slava. Edited the question correctly now. Is it making the right sense now?

Comment: @Gokul Glad it helped you at last.